# Solidity deterministic shuffle algorithm

Tags: solidity, randomness, algorithm

I'm finding a deterministic shuffle algorithm

```
function shuffle(unit256 seed, uint256 length, uint256 index) external returns (uint256);
```

Given the same `seed` and `length`. different index input will never get the same output and the output will never be greater or equal to length.

Is there anything like this algorithm out there?

Answer (score 0):

I got an idea to mimic the card shuffle behavior.

1. Randomize the shuffle index using seed, The result will be `0` to `length-1`
2. Swap left and right members using the shuffle index form 1.
3. Repeat step 1 until we reach the desired amount of rounds.

This one preserves unpredictability if the seed cannot be known ahead.
But it still has a low discrepancy.
Causes issues with randomness on continuous indexes.

Comment: Good to add more details on handling continuous indexes and further explanation on why the method preserves unpredictability.